# « Tu aurais dû me le laisser faire » ou « Tu aurais dû me laisser le faire » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots, infinitif, au

Ma question se trouve dans le titre ; voici les raisons pour lesquelles je ne suis pas sûr du choix. En fait, je crois que c'est la première qui est correcte, mais ma copine, qui est française, me dit que la deuxième est plus correcte à ses oreilles.

Pour ma part, je citerais trois règles:

- Le pronom complément se place devant le verbe dont il est le complément;
- Le pronom se place devant le groupe « verbe + infinitif » avec laisser et faire;
- Avec 2 pronoms, dans ce cas « me » et « le », on écrit dans l'ordre « me le ».

Elles me permettent d'arriver à ma conclusion parce que:

- « aurais dû » n’a pas de complément, donc on continue sans s'en occuper
- « laisser faire » constitue un groupe de la forme « laisser + infinitif », donc ses pronoms complément se placent avant
- On a besoin de deux pronoms complément dans ce cas, et donc, on écrit « me le »
- Enfin, on écrit ainsi: « tu aurais dû me le laisser faire »

Par contre, ma première idée était que la deuxième phrase était correcte, parce que c’est « faire » qui a le complément « le » et « laisser » qui a le complément « me ». Ce n’est qu'après avoir lu un chapitre de mon livre qui parle de l’idée d’un « groupe » que j’ai commencé à douter et ainsi, à penser qu’en fait c'est la première phrase qui est correcte.

Si je me suis trompé dans mon raisonnement ci-dessus (en ce qui concerne la première phrase), en quoi ? Sinon, cela veut-il dire que c’est en effet le premier qui est correct ?

Indice qui tend à prouver que j'ai tort : [selon Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=me%20le%20laisser%20faire%2C%20me%20laisser%20le%20faire&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3), c'est en fait la deuxième tournure qui est la plus employée. Cela étant dit, ce n'est qu'une tendance récente, peut-être est-ce donc une conséquence de l'écriture brouillonne des textos. Je n'en sais rien.

Comment: To me both are correct but usage may depend on the context. For instance: "Tu as fait le repassage? Tu aurais dû me le laisser faire." but "La tarte est trop cuite. Tu aurais dû me laisser faire".

Comment: L'idée dans l'avant dernière phrase ne semble pas clairement énoncée et je ne comprend pas ; je ne sais donc pas comment l'améliorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are valid but usage strongly differ.

The second form:

> Tu aurais du me laisser le faire.

is by far the most common one. It can be used whatever the language register.

The first form:

> Tu aurais du me le laisser faire.

was common in the past but is now outdated and might only used in a literary context.

[Reference](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/pronoms-1.html#3142) (*Guide de gram­mai­re française pour étudiants fin­no­pho­nes*) :

> c. Dans la langue classique, les pro­noms *le la les* com­plé­ment direct d’un in­fi­ni­tif dé­pen­dant d’un ver­be prin­ci­pal se placent devant le ver­be principal :
>
> J’ai seulement compris que la vie que je mène à Paris est encore plus agréable que je ne **le** pouvais croire. [Mme du Deffand]. On dit qu’il y a des gens fort polis dans cette ville-là ; je **le** veux croire. [Voltaire]
>
> Les for­mes cor­res­pon­dantes en français standard seraient : *je ne pouvais le croire, je veux le croire*. Certains écrivains d’aujourd’hui écrivent encore de cette façon un peu archaïque qui est tout à fait admise dans le *style soutenu*. Mais dans la langue cou­rante, cela passe pour affecté ou franchement fautif. On en trouve ce­pen­dant des em­plois épisodiques dans la langue cou­rante, par ignorance ou hy­per­cor­rec­tis­me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I wonder if you can expand a bit on how and why the second form came about, and in particular, why it is ok to violate (or perhaps it does not violate because of some exception I don't know about) the rules I cited above. In particular, is « laisser faire » not a single verb group in this case? And are there other cases which follow this same model?

Comment: Reference added.

Answer (score 2):

On trouve ci-dessus dans l'ordre des personnes de la conjugaison des verbes les six n-grams des paires « pronCOI pronCOD laisser faire/pronCOI laisser pronCOD faire », en tenant compte que pour les troisièmes personnes une inversion des pronoms est nécessaire dans le premier élément de la paire.

**1** [me le laisser faire,
me laisser le faire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=me+le+laisser+faire%2C+me+laisser+le+faire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cme%20le%20laisser%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cme%20laisser%20le%20faire%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cme%20le%20laisser%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cme%20laisser%20le%20faire%3B%2Cc0)
**2** [te le laisser faire,te laisser le faire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=te+le+laisser+faire%2C+te+laisser+le+faire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cte%20laisser%20le%20faire%3B%2Cc0)
**3** [le lui laisser faire,lui laisser le faire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+lui+laisser+faire%2C+lui+laisser+le+faire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20lui%20laisser%20faire%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cle%20lui%20laisser%20faire%3B%2Cc0)
**4** [nous le laisser faire,nous laisser le faire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nous+le+laisser+faire%2C+nous+laisser+le+faire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnous%20le%20laisser%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnous%20laisser%20le%20faire%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnous%20le%20laisser%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnous%20laisser%20le%20faire%3B%2Cc0)
**5** [vous le laisser faire,vous laisser le faire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vous+le+laisser+faire%2C+vous+laisser+le+faire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvous%20le%20laisser%20faire%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cvous%20le%20laisser%20faire%3B%2Cc0)
**6** [le leur laisser faire,leur laisser le faire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+leur+laisser+faire%2C+leur+laisser+le+faire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20leur%20laisser%20faire%3B%2Cc0)

**ngram 1**

[image]

**ngram 2**

[image]

**ngram 3**

[image]

**ngram 4**

[image]

**ngram 5**

[image]

**ngram 6**

[image]

Le tableau ci-dessous est une récapitulation de certaines observations suite à un examen des six ngrams. Il se lit selon les conventions suivantes.

- Seulement les formes en caractères gras sont trouvées dans les livres.
- Les tirets montrent des formes qui fluctuent au cours des ans.
- « 1 » signifie qu'en dernière date la forme est dominante.
- « 2 » signifie qu'en dernière date la forme est moins utilisée.
- « 0 » signifie que l'on ne trouve pas la forme.

| FORME | CARACTÉRISTIQUE |
| --- | --- |
| **me le laisser faire** | **-** **2** |
| **me laisser le faire** | **-** **1** |
| -------------------- |  |
| te le laisser faire | **0** |
| **te laisser le faire** | **1** |
| -------------------- |  |
| **le lui laisser faire** | **1** |
| lui laisser le faire | **0** |
| -------------------- |  |
| **nous le laisser faire** | **-** **2** |
| **nous laisser le faire** | **-** **1** |
| -------------------- |  |
| **vous le laisser faire** | **1** |
| vous laisser le faire | **0** |
| -------------------- |  |
| **le leur laisser faire** | **1** |
| leur laisser le faire | **0** |

En conclusion il peut être dit que les deux formes se trouvent aux premières personnes seulement et que présentement *la seconde*  est celle qui est préférée.
Pour les quatre autres personnes une seule forme est trouvée dans les livres et c'est *la première*, sauf, cas exceptionnel, pour la seconde personne du singulier.

Je pense que toutes les formes sont acceptables, même lorsqu'on ne les trouve pas dans les livres, sauf les deux ci-dessous; cependant, je ne connais pas de source qui puisse confirmer cette contention.

- **lui laisser le faire**, **leur laisser le faire**

Comment: Merci pour toutes les données ! Super utile.